# What is difference Between Base64 and Multipart?

Tags: android, base64, multipart

Can any one explain what is the advantage of  `Base64` as well `Multipart`

> I know Multipart is faster then `Base64`...

But still many developers are using Base64...I studied both documentation but i am not clear

Comment: You cannot compare base64 with multipart. They have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 45):

**Base64**
Base64 is a way to encode binary data into an ASCII character format by translating it into a radix-64 representation.

I recommend that you never use Base64 for large file/data upload to the server because it converts whole data and posts it to the server.

**Multipart**
Multipart is a way to upload files/data to a server in the form of parts which are in bytes. Multipart/form-data is applied to a form though so that you can send everything in a multi-part form, including "regular" data also.

Comment: It is worth noting though that in most (all?) cases, binary multipart/form-data data is encoded as base64.

Comment: What do you mean with "large file/data" ? > 5mo ? > 10mo ? > 500mo ?

Comment: @PierreD large is relative to year, to internet speed of client, etc. Multipart is there to split file into multiple parts and send them part by part, so that you can show progress, and each part is independently handled. So let's say 5mb to 10mb is large enough for an image if you're not showing any progression on a slow network.

Answer (score 7):

Multipart ist a part of the http protocol. See

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19712083/5694629

Base64 is a way to convert arbitrary content into a serializable form for transmission.

Comment: can you tell me sir what is serializable,why we have to use.@pat_b13

Comment: Serialization is used to transmit data from one component to another (e.g. from your server to your smartphone). It's done in a form that both components can understand, mostly with the ASCII format, as this is common since long time. Base64 will transform your data into a stream of ASCII characters which can be read by almost any computer component.

Comment: thank you sir..i am sry to disdrap you sir....i think Deserialization means (mobile to server data transfer or what sir...can you tell me please....

Comment: Deserialization is the opposite of serialization. The sender component serializes the data to transmit and the recipient DEserializes the stream of data. The whole process is called 'Serialization'. As ASCII is a common character encoding, it's used for serialization. Base64 contains only ASCII, so it's used to switch your data into a form that can be easily serialized and deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

**Base64 Encoding:**
Base64 encoding is a method to represent binary data in ASCII text format. It takes binary data and transforms it into a text-based format, using a limited set of characters like A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, and padding characters like "=".

**Advantages:**

- Suitable for embedding binary data within text-based formats like
  JSON or XML.
- List item It ensures that binary data can be safely transmitted in
  contexts that might not handle binary data well.

**Disadvantages:**

- Increases data size by about 33% because binary data is represented as text
- May not be the most efficient choice for very large files due to
  increased data size.

Base64 encoding is beneficial when you need to include binary data within a structured text-based document, such as embedding images or other binary resources in JSON payloads.

**Multipart File Upload:**

Multipart file upload is a standard approach for sending binary files in an HTTP request. It uses the "multipart/form-data" content type for HTTP POST requests. In this method, binary files are included directly in the request body as parts, and you can add metadata, such as file names and content types

**- Advantages:**

- Efficient for uploading large binary files, as it doesn't inflate data size.
- Supports sending multiple files within a single request.
- Provides flexibility to include metadata about the uploaded files.

**Disadvantages:**

- Requires additional HTTP headers and a more complex request structure
  compared to Base64 encoding.
- May not be as straightforward for embedding binary data in structured
  text-based formats like JSON.

Multipart file upload is the preferred choice when you need to efficiently transmit binary files, especially large ones, and require metadata about those files. It's commonly used in scenarios where users upload images, documents, or other files through web forms.

Multipart file upload is the preferred choice when you need to efficiently transmit binary files, especially large ones, and require metadata about those files. It's commonly used in scenarios where users upload images, documents, or other files through web forms.